# Handle permissions with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-permissions

I'm new to app development, and I'm using Xamarin forms for cross-platform support. I don't understand when to ask for permissions, though. Do I ask on demand, when I need to use the camera, for instance, or do I ask when the app is loaded? If I ask on demand, I can do that with a helper function, but if I ask when the app is loaded, when do I do that? Is there a function I should override or do it in the OnCreate() function?

Also, do I only need to do this in the Android code or do I need to write code for the iOS project as well?

Also, what is the OnRequestPermissionsResult function used for? Do I need to write any code inside that function?

I set the permissions in the Android's project property sheet in Visual Studio, and I edited the info.plist file directly for the iOS project, but beyond that, I'm lost, so any advice people have on permissions would be appreciated.

I'm using a Xamarin Shell app that was auto-generated in Visual Studio. The auto-generated code uses the Xamarin.Essentials library for permissions, which sounds great, but I have no idea how to use that class.

Comment: If your android version is starting with android 6.0, you need runtime permission for storage in this question. `Android app(Xamarin)`：You could download the source file from the link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows
`Xamarin.Forms`:Please check the Plugin.Permissions with runtime permission. It is a simple cross platform plugin to request and check permissions. Download the sample code from the link below.
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Answer (score 3):

**Android**:

> Permissions are declared in the AndroidManifest.xml by the application
>   developer when the app is developed. Android has two different
>   workflows for obtaining the user's consent for those permissions:
>
> For apps that targeted Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower, the permission request occurred when the app was installed.
>
> If the user
>   did not grant the permissions, then the app would not be installed.
>   Once the app is installed, there is no way to revoke the permissions
>   except by uninstalling the app.
>       Starting in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users were given more control over permissions; they can grant or revoke permissions as long
>   as the app is installed on the device.

You need to set the manifest for each permission, but the user won't be notified until the permission is actually used.  Haven't you ever noticed this from existing apps?  The permissions can be granted one at a time and denied one at a time.

> **Android apps must check at run-time to see if they have permission to**
>   **access a protected resource.** If the app does not have permission, then
>   it must make requests using the new APIs provided by the Android SDK
>   for the user to grant the permissions. Permissions are divided into
>   two categories:
>
> Normal Permissions – These are permissions which pose little security risk to the user's security or privacy. Android 6.0 will
>   automatically grant normal permissions at the time of installation.
>   Please consult the Android documentation for a complete list of normal
>   permissions.
>
> Dangerous Permissions – In contrast to normal permissions, dangerous permissions are those that protect the user's security or
>   privacy. These must be explictly granted by the user. Sending or
>   receiving an SMS message is an example of an action requiring a
>   dangerous permission.

**In order to set the manifest permissions on Android, right click on the project `MyApp.Android` in your solution explorer then select "properties" and go to "Android Manifest" then scroll to the bottom and select them as needed.**

> The first step in working with Android permissions is to declare the
>   permissions in the Android manifest file. This must be done regardless
>   of the API level that the app is targetting.
>
> Apps that target Android 6.0 or higher cannot assume that because the
>   user granted permission at some point in the past, that the permission
>   will be valid the next time. An app that targets Android 6.0 must
>   always perform a runtime permission check. Apps that target Android
>   5.1 or lower do not need to perform a run-time permission check.
>
> Is there a function I should override or do it in the OnCreate()
>   function?

You can ask for permissions in the `OnCreate` override if you want; I'd just use helper functions called from it opposed to jamming code in there.  If I were you I'd try to avoid asking all at once unless you have to.  Just test it out without doing that, seems like it'd make for a weird user experience if they get asked right when the app loads.

Note

**Applications should only request the permissions that they require.**

I've never had to use this method but you can try it; it goes in `MainActivity.cs`, some say it's needed:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
   string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult
          (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}`
```

^^^ method gets called when the permissions are requested and you can put whatever code you want in there on top of the `base.OnRequestPermissionsResult()`

My apps always worked without that.  I think it's just for if you want to add extra code on the permissions request result.  I'd try without it first then if you're not getting expected behavior you can add it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows

**iOS:**

I'm not as personally familiar with Xamarin.iOS but here's from the docs:

> Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio currently doesn't support editing the
>   Info.plist privacy keys from within the default iOS manifest editor.
>   Instead you will need to use the generic PList editor, so do the
>   following:
>
> Right-click on the Info.plist file in the Solution Explorer and select Open with....
>
> Select the Generic PList Editor from the list of programs to open the file, then click OK.

^^ docs say that but in my Xamarin I can right click on the App.iOS project > go to properties > iOS manifest and there is a designer.

> Accessing Private User Data
>   Apps running on iOS 10 (or later) must statically declare their intent
>   to access specific features or user information by entering one or
>   more Privacy Keys in their Info.plist files that explain to the user
>   why the app wishes to gain access.
>
> **Apps that fail to provide the required keys will be silently
>   terminated by the system when they attempt to access one of the
>   restricted features or user information, without error! If an app
>   starts unexpectedly failing on iOS 10, ensure that all of the required
>   Info.plist have been specified.**

**Permissions are stored in info.plist**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: That is helpful background information, thank you. Even though I had read about the differences before and after Android 6.0, I didn't understand it until you clarified it.

I found this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PORPI6Q5t2Y) that showed how to modify the OnCreate function in the Android specific code to ask for permissions when the app starts. Since my app needs GPS and camera permission to do anything useful, I'm asking for the permissions at the start and then going to a landing page if they don't allow it, saying I need permission to do anything useful.

Comment: @JeffLorenzini For the runtime prmissions of Xamarin.forms, check the link i provided in previous comment. If you still have this problem, provide the code.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using a Xamarin Shell app that was auto-generated in Visual
>   Studio. The auto-generated code uses the Xamarin.Essentials library
>   for permissions, which sounds great, but I have no idea how to use
>   that class.

Xamarin.Essentials library are not used for permissions as they don't have such a feature on their list. However, they do ask for permissions for the functions that they provide when those functions are used in the app (no code required from your side), but there is no way to do something like 'ask for a permission for the feature X now'.

As explained in the documentation you need to add this code to make it work properly:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Some of the functions in Xamarin.Essentials may require changes in Android manifest or Info.plist file on iOS, and that is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/android and there is no space to go function by function here.